# Is there any way I can specify defaultValue for collections with JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd, xjc

I have this attribute in Java

```java
@XmlList
@XmlElement(defaultValue = "COMMENTS CASE_INSENSITIVE")
protected List<RegexFlag> regexFlags;
```

Which has been generated from XJC, originating from this XSD:

```xml
<element name="regexFlags" type="tns:RegexFlags" 
    minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" default="COMMENTS CASE_INSENSITIVE"/>

<simpleType name="RegexFlags">
  <list itemType="tns:RegexFlag"/>
</simpleType>

<simpleType name="RegexFlag">
  <restriction base="string">
    <enumeration value="UNIX_LINES"/>
    <enumeration value="CASE_INSENSITIVE"/>
    <enumeration value="COMMENTS"/>
    <enumeration value="MULTILINE"/>
    <enumeration value="LITERAL"/>
    <enumeration value="DOTALL"/>
    <enumeration value="UNICODE_CASE"/>
    <enumeration value="CANON_EQ"/>
    <enumeration value="UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS"/>
  </restriction>
</simpleType>
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work. The default values are not unmarshalled correctly. The value I get when I don't have a `<regexFlags/>` element is really just an empty list. What am I doing wrong? Is this even possible with JAXB?

Comment: Judging from the source code, this should actually theoretically be possible.

Comment: @lexicore: I believe that this is a bug in JAXB - [see my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27550877/521799)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `defaultValue` property on the `@XmlElement` annotation, is what a JAXB (JSR-222) implementation should swap in for the value of an empty element.  Their appears to be a bug in the reference and MOXy implementations of this when that element is mapped to a property annotated with `@XmlList`.

### Domain Model

**Root**

Here is a sample class with 3 `String` and 3 `List<String>` fields all annotated with `@XmlElement(defaultValue="a b c")`.  The `List<String>` fields are also annotated with `@XmlList`.

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root {

    @XmlElement(defaultValue="a b c")
    String singleMissingElement;

    @XmlElement(defaultValue="a b c")
    String singleEmptyElement;

    @XmlElement(defaultValue="a b c")
    String singlePopulatedElement;

    @XmlElement(defaultValue="a b c")
    @XmlList
    List<String> listMissingElement;

    @XmlElement(defaultValue="a b c")
    @XmlList
    List<String> listEmptyElement;

    @XmlElement(defaultValue="a b c")
    @XmlList
    List<String> listPopulatedElement;

}
```

### Demo Code

**Demo**

Below is some demo code that unmarshals some XML and outputs the resulting fields from the object.  The XML elements are populated based on the fields name (i.e. `missing` means absent from the XML, `empty` means empty element, and `populated` means element with a value).

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);

        StringReader xml = new StringReader("<root><singleEmptyElement/><singlePopulatedElement>populated</singlePopulatedElement><listEmptyElement/><listPopulatedElement>populated</listPopulatedElement></root>");
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        Root root = (Root) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        System.out.println(root.singleMissingElement);
        System.out.println(root.singleEmptyElement);
        System.out.println(root.singlePopulatedElement);

        System.out.println(root.listMissingElement);
        System.out.println(root.listEmptyElement);
        System.out.println(root.listPopulatedElement);
    }

}
```

**Output**

The only value that comes out unexpectedly is the 5th one which corresponds to the empty element for the `List<String>` field.  Based on the `defaultValue` I would have expected it to be a `List` that contained the strings `a`, `b`, and `c`.

```
null
a b c
populated
null
[]
[populated]
```

---

### Why is this the Behaviour for `defaultValue` on `@XmlElement`?

**XML Schema (schema.xsd)**

The `defaultValue` property on the `@XmlElement` annotation corresponds to the `default` property on an `element` declaration in an XML Schema.  Below is the schema equivalent of what we have annotated in our Java model.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="root" type="root"/>

  <xs:complexType name="root">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="singleMissingElement" type="xs:string" default="a b c" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="singleEmptyElement" type="xs:string" default="a b c" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="singlePopulatedElement" type="xs:string" default="a b c" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="listMissingElement" minOccurs="0" default="a b c">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:list itemType="xs:string"/>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="listEmptyElement" minOccurs="0" default="a b c">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:list itemType="xs:string"/>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="listPopulatedElement" minOccurs="0" default="a b c">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:list itemType="xs:string"/>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

**Demo Code**

Below is some code that will do a SAX parse with schema validation enabled where the `ContentHandler` dumps some info to `System.out`.

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.validation.*;
import org.xml.sax.*;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class ParseDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        Schema schema = sf.newSchema(new File("src/forum27528698/schema.xsd")); 

        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        spf.setSchema(schema);
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
        xr.setContentHandler(new MyHandler());

        StringReader xml = new StringReader("<root><singleEmptyElement/><singlePopulatedElement>populated</singlePopulatedElement><listEmptyElement/><listPopulatedElement>populated</listPopulatedElement></root>");
        InputSource input = new InputSource(xml);
        xr.parse(input);
    }

    private static class MyHandler extends DefaultHandler {

        @Override
        public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
            System.out.print("<" + qName + ">");
        }

        @Override
        public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
            System.out.print(new String(ch, start, length));
        }

        @Override
        public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
            System.out.println("</" + qName + ">");
        }

    }

}
```

**Output**

In the output we see that the default value has been applied to the empty elements, but not the absent ones.

```
<root>
<singleEmptyElement>a b c</singleEmptyElement>
<singlePopulatedElement>populated</singlePopulatedElement>
<listEmptyElement>a b c</listEmptyElement>
<listPopulatedElement>populated</listPopulatedElement>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your extensive answer. I actually wasn't aware of the semantics of `default` in XSD (although I also didn't give this too much thought). So there had been a misunderstanding on how XSD / JAXB work on my side, possibly mixed with a bug in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a misunderstanding of JAXB's idea of a `defaultValue` in the original question (or quite frankly, just a bug). This piece of code explains it:

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
import static javax.xml.bind.JAXB.unmarshal;

import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlList;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        out.println(unmarshal(new StringReader("<x></x>"), X.class));
        out.println(unmarshal(new StringReader("<x><flags/></x>"), X.class));
        out.println(unmarshal(new StringReader("<x><flags>X Y</flags></x>"), X.class));
    }
}

@XmlRootElement
class X {

    @XmlList
    @XmlElement(defaultValue = "A B")
    protected List<String> flags;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "X [flags=" + flags + "]";
    }
}
```

The output of the above is

```
X [flags=null]
X [flags=[A, B]]
X [flags=[X, Y]]
```

So, apparently, the mere presence of the relevant element is important. If it is absent, the `defaultValue` is not applied. If it is present but the value is absent, then the `defaultValue` is applied.

#### Workaround

The following workaround can be used to enforce these `defaultValues`:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        X x1 = unmarshal(new StringReader("<x></x>"), X.class);
        X x2 = unmarshal(new StringReader("<x><flags/></x>"), X.class);
        X x3 = unmarshal(new StringReader("<x><flags>X Y</flags></x>"), X.class);

        out.println("First unmarshal:");
        out.println(x1);
        out.println(x2);
        out.println(x3);

        // Marshal the xml again. This will add the <flags/> element
        StringWriter s1 = new StringWriter(); JAXB.marshal(x1, s1);
        StringWriter s2 = new StringWriter(); JAXB.marshal(x2, s2);
        StringWriter s3 = new StringWriter(); JAXB.marshal(x3, s3);

        // Now we're talking!
        x1 = unmarshal(new StringReader(s1.toString()), X.class);
        x2 = unmarshal(new StringReader(s2.toString()), X.class);
        x3 = unmarshal(new StringReader(s3.toString()), X.class);

        out.println();
        out.println("Second unmarshal:");
        out.println(x1);
        out.println(x2);
        out.println(x3);
    }
}
```

And the annotations have to be moved from the attribute to the getter, with explicit lazy initialisation of the list in place (which is why this smells like a bug to me).

```
@XmlRootElement
class X {

    protected List<String> flags;

    @XmlList
    @XmlElement(defaultValue = "A B")
    public List<String> getFlags() {
        if (flags == null)
            flags = new ArrayList<>();

        return flags;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "X [flags=" + flags + "]";
    }
}
```

Behold, the output is now "correct"...

```
First unmarshal:
X [flags=null]
X [flags=[A, B]]
X [flags=[X, Y]]

Second unmarshal:
X [flags=[A, B]]
X [flags=[A, B]]
X [flags=[X, Y]]
```

This all reminds me of...

```
System.gc();
System.gc(); // Just to be sure
```

;-)

Comment: Could you please also post the code of the `JAXB` class. You don't cache the unmarshaller, do you?

Comment: @lexicore: What you see is all there is :-). You already have the code of the `JAXB` class: `javax.xml.bind.JAXB` (see also the posted import statements). It does contain a cache, but I'm not sure how that would be related...

Comment: Which version of the JDK are you using.  I would expect you to get `X [flags=[A, B]]` when you unmarshalled `<x><flags/></x>` but that's not what I'm seeing.

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan: build 1.8.0_40-ea-b12